# Django models foreignkey default value

Tags: python, django, django-models

There was no manager in the posts I created before. When I add the manager, I want the default value or I am asked to enter it manually. When I enter 'None' I get an error like this;

> django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed:
>   new__Core_post.manager_id

I cannot export PostManager as the default value. Is there another way or another solution to give?

```
class User(models.Model):
    #...
    posts = models.ManyToManyField('Post', blank=True)

class Post(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    #...
    manager = models.ForeignKey('PostManager', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class PostManager(models.Model):
    #...
```

> Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Well since it is a non-nullable field, you can not pass `None` to it. You can for example pass a primary key to it, and then it will link the posts to *that* `Manager`.

Comment: Do you want to allow `Post`s without manager? If so, set `null=True` on your field (and maybe `on_delete=models.SET_NULL`). Otherwise, choose your default manager as Willem mentioned above.